# Describe a mathematical problem

Tags: mathematics, computing, science

How can I make the bold part of this sentence less awful?

> **The symbolic regression problem is the problem of** finding a closed form that models...

You can move around the second part of the sentence, but not modify it.

Comment: What makes you think the sentence is "awful"? Whatever - I don't know if they're all copying each other, but there are four different publications with [*The symbolic regression problem **is to find a function**, in symbolic form, that fits a given data set*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=The+symbolic+regression+problem+is+to+find+a+function%2C+in+symbolic+form%2C+that+fits+a+given+data+set.&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22The+symbolic+regression+problem+is+to+find+a+function%2C+in+symbolic+form%2C+that+fits+a+given+data+set%22)

Comment: Your sentence is better than most of the suggestions in the answers!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest alternative I see is

> "The symbolic regression problem is that of finding a closed form..."

But if I understand your aim correctly, you may also want to use a synonym for the first instance of 'problem' that matches closely with 'goal'.

> "The goal/purpose/aim of symbolic regression is finding a closed form..."

Or if you mean to emphasize the difficulty in actually doing symbolic regression, I'd use a synonym in that direction.

> "The challenge of symbolic regression is the problem of finding a closed form..."

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the language means, it work to say,

> "The symbolic regression problem is **to find** a closed
>   form that models..."

Or perhaps you could substitute "**issue**" or "**question**" for "**problem**."

Answer (score -1):

Some minor variations on the answers already submitted:

> The symbolic regression problem is one of finding a closed form …

> The essence of the symbolic regression problem is finding a closed form …

> The essence of symbolic regression is finding a closed form …